# CSS transform rotate with distortion

Tags: css

Below is the my code

http://liveweave.com/ks0njD

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
```

and CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.box1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: .5s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.box2{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  transform: translateY(68px) rotate(-45deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;

  transition: .5s ease;
    perspective: 1000px;

}
.container:hover .box1{
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  transition: .8s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.container:hover .box2 {
  transform: translateY(84px) rotate(-60deg);
  transition: .8s ease;
  backface-visibility: hiddeni;
}
```

As you can see, when the divs rotate there is slight distortion, is there anyway i can make this look perfect ? i tried using backface and perspective but doesnt makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

@Amer what you mean from 'look perfect'? Something like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.box1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  background: black;
  top: 112px;
  left: 200px;
  background:#3ac7f2;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: .5s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
   perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.box2{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  background: black;
  top: 93px;
  left: 200px;
  background:#3ac7f2;
  transform: translateY(68px) rotate(-45deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: .5s ease;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.container:hover .box1{
  background:#09F;
  transform:background .4s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: .8s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.container:hover .box2 {
  background:#09F;
  transform:background .4s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(68px) rotate(45deg);
  transition: .8s ease;
  backface-visibility: hiddeni;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```